# SQL server: select all json array elements using JSON_QUERY

Tags: json, sql-server, select, json-query, json-value

I have a column `myColumn` in `myTable` table with this value:

```
"6285":[
         {
           "75963":{"lookupId":"54","value":"0","version":null},
           "75742":{"lookupId":"254","value":"991","version":null}
         }
       ]
```

I need to write `select` query using `JSON_VALUE` or `JSON_QUERY` functions (my `sql server` version does not support `OPENJSON`). The query should return this result:

```
"75963-0, 75742-991"
```

As you can see I need values of `value` parameter. Also note that I don't know what elements will an object inside `6285` array contain. I mean I wouldn't know in advance that there will be 2 elements (75963 and  75742) in it. There could be more or less elements and they could be different of course. **However** there will always be only one object in `6285` array.

What kind of `select` can I write to achieve it?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version? If you can use `JSON_QUERY()`, you should be able to use `OPENJSON()`.

Comment: @Zhorov `Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64) 
 Aug 22 2017 17:04:49 
 Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)`. Maybe it is possible to use `OPENJSON` in sql editor, but I am querying using `Hibernate` (Java framework) and it does not support `OPENJSON` I think. But If you could write a query using `OPENJSON` it would also help.

Answer (score 3):

It's strange, I think that your version supports `OPENJSON()` and you may try to use the following statement. Note, that the JSON in the question is not valid, it should be inside `{}`.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (JsonColumn varchar(1000))
INSERT INTO Data (JsonColumn) 
VALUES ('{"6285":[{"75963":{"lookupId":"54","value":"0","version":null},"75742":{"lookupId":"254","value":"991","version":null}}]}')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT CONCAT(j2.[key], '-', JSON_VALUE(j2.[value], '$.value')) AS JsonValue
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.JsonColumn) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value], '$[0]') j2
```

Result:

```
JsonValue
---------
75963-0
75742-991
```

If you need an aggregated result, you may use `STRING_AGG()`:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(j2.[key], '-', JSON_VALUE(j2.[value], '$.value')), ',') AS JsonValue
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.JsonColumn) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value], '$[0]') j2
```

Result:

```
JsonValue
-----------------
75963-0,75742-991
```